# How to find where UIWebView is being included in my project

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

another UIWebView question. I've started working on a project that is being rejected by Apple with the following error:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

I've successfully removed references to UIWebView on other projects, but I can't find where the reference is coming from in this case.

So far I've tried the following:

1. Searched for references to `UIWebView` in the project, and confirmed that there are none.
2. Searched for references in dependencies using `grep -r UIWebView .`, and confirmed that there are none (after updating dependencies for the ones I found).
3. Updated all pods to the latest versions.

However when I inspect the binary by running `nm MyProject.app/MyProject | grep UIWebView` it returns `U _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIWebView`, i.e. the reference is still there, hence it is still being rejected by Apple.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can locate where that reference is coming from?

Comment: its probably being referenced by some dependencies you have, are you usnig pods? might be worth making sure they are all up to date

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Scriptable, I've already tried that.

Comment: @GabrielleEarnshaw The following article may help: [Determining which frameworks use UIWebView](https://blog.kulman.sk/determining-which-frameworks-use-uiwebview/).

Comment: @GabrielleEarnshaw did you solve this?